# How to make in-place changes to values between two dictionaries provided the value in dictionary1 is the same as Key in dictionary2?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, the first is a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
dict = {k1:{kk1:vv1, kk2: vv2}, k2:{kkk1:vvv1, kkk2:vvv2}}

dict1 = dict['k2']
# So basically:
# dict1 = {kkk1:vvv1, kkk2:vvv2}

dict3 = {vvv1:actualv1, vvv2:actualv2}
```

I want the end result to be:

```
dict1 = {kkk1:actualv1, kkk2:actualv2}
```

Which is basically:

```
dict = {k1:{kk1:vv1, kk2: vv2}, k2:{kkk1:actualv1, kkk2:actualv2}}
```

So, I have tried dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: dict2.get(v, v) for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

But to no avail. I have tried to be as clear as possible. One more thing I'd like to mention is that The 'dict' contains about 400 k-v pairs. I have given an example of what I would like to achieve. Help.

Comment: Is `k2` a given value or do you want to "patch" all of the inner dictionaries according to your `dict3`?

Comment: `{kk1:vv1, kk2, vv2}` is not a valid dictionary. Did you mean `{kk1:vv1, kk2:vv2}`?

Comment: Your dictionary has syntactical mistakes. Pls reformat them for easy reproduction.

Comment: @Alfe k1, k2 and so on are all headers in a csv. I want to replace the values in dict1 with values in dict3, the values in dict1 are the same as values in dict2. Once these values are replaces, I'd like to update the inner dictionary 
 in dict with the newly updated dict1. (Is that even possible?)

Comment: @Ajax1234 yes, that is what I meant. Edit complete.

Comment: Dictionaries are mutable objects.  That means, if you change the inner dictionary in-place, then the outer dictionary reflects that change instantly.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Patching the `dict1` alone and inplace, accordint to `dict3`, can be done like this:

```
d = dict(k1=dict(kk1='vv1', kk2='vv2'),
         k2=dict(kkk1='vvv1', kkk2='vvv2'))
dict1 = d['k2']
dict3 = dict(vvv1='actualv1', vvv2='actualv2')

for k in dict1:
  v = dict1[k]
  try:
    dict1[k] = dict3[v]
  except KeyError:
    pass

print d
```

prints:

```
{'k2': {'kkk2': 'actualv2', 'kkk1': 'actualv1'},
 'k1': {'kk1': 'vv1', 'kk2': 'vv2'}}
```

Comment: I hope you can make this into a proper function yourself.  Feel free to ask if something's unclear about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dict = {'k1':{'kk1':'vv1', 'kk2': 'vv2'}, 'k2':{'kkk1':'vvv1', 'kkk2':'vvv2'}}
dict3 = {'vvv1':'actualv1', 'vvv2':'actualv2'}
final_data = {a:{c:dict3.get(d, d) for c, d in b.items()} for a, b in dict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'k1': {'kk1': 'vv1', 'kk2': 'vv2'}, 'k2': {'kkk1': 'actualv1', 'kkk2': 'actualv2'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want to process a sub dict from a dict of dicts, given its key, and replace values according to a replacement dict original_value => replacement_value.

You can just do it:

```
def patch_dic(dic, key, dict3):
    for k,v in dic[key].items():             # iterate the sub dict
        for orig, repl in dict3.items():     # iterate the replacement dict
            if v == orig:                    # if a value exists in the replacement dict
                dic[key][k] = repl           # just replace it
```

Demo:

```
>>> dic = {'k1':{'kk1':'vv1', 'kk2': 'vv2'}, 'k2':{'kkk1':'vvv1', 'kkk2':'vvv2'}}
>>> patch_dic(dic, 'k2', {'vvv1':'actualv1', 'vvv2':'actualv2'})
>>> print(dic)
{'k1': {'kk1': 'vv1', 'kk2': 'vv2'}, 'k2': {'kkk1': 'actualv1', 'kkk2': 'actualv2'}}
```